# What are the different options for excluding certain post types from search results?

Tags: search

I am aware of the option to set `exclude_from_search => 'true'` when registering a custom post type. But what are the other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook. Do note though, this hook filters the query on both the front-end and admin. For example, we could do something like this:

```
function search_post_types( $query ) {
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return $query;
    }

    if ( $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_post_types' );
```

I'm not sure there's a way to *exclude* it using `pre_get_posts` but more along the lines of include specific post types only, in the example above I'm only including Posts and Pages, nothing else.

---

Another method is to get *all* post types and create an array of post types we actually want to exclude. First we use the function [`get_post_types()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) which **does** have some arguments to exclude built-in post types but for this example we will get everything. Once we've gotten our post types we can create an exclude array and [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php), here's what it looks like:

```
function search_post_types( $query ) {
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return $query;
    }

    if ( $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $post_types = get_post_types( array(), 'names' );                   // With no arguments, this should never be empty
        if( ! empty( $post_types ) ) {                                      // But let's check just to be safe!
            $pt_exclude = array( 'attachment', 'revision', 'nav_menu_item' );
            $pt_include = array_diff( $post_types, $pt_exclude );

            $query->set( 'post_type', $pt_include );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_post_types' );
```

Comment: Thanks. Should it be $query->is_search ?

Comment: @codecowboy You're right good catch! I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the pre_get_posts hook and check that the query is a search query:

```
function my_theme_pre_get_posts( WP_Query $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
        ...
    }

    return $query;
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_theme_pre_get_posts' );
```

Comment: `pre_get_posts` is an action. From core code `do_action_ref_array( 'pre_get_posts', array( &$this ) );`. You also don't need to return the variable in an action :-)